# Find the position of an element within its parent with XSLT / XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath, position, exslt

Apart from rewriting a lot of XSLT code (which I'm not going to do), is there a way to find the position of an element within its parent, when the context is arbitrarily set to something else? Here's an example:

```
<!-- Here are my records-->
<xsl:for-each select="/path/to/record">
  <xsl:variable name="record" select="."/>

  <!-- At this point, I could use position() -->
  <!-- Set the context to the current record -->
  <xsl:for-each select="$record">

    <!-- At this point, position() is meaningless because it's always 1 -->
    <xsl:call-template name="SomeTemplate"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>


<!-- This template expects the current context being set to a record -->
<xsl:template name="SomeTemplate">

  <!-- it does stuff with the record's fields -->
  <xsl:value-of select="SomeRecordField"/>

  <!-- How to access the record's position in /path/to or in any other path? -->
</xsl:template>
```

**NOTE:** This is a simplified example. I have several constraints keeping me from implementing obvious solutions, such as passing new parameters to `SomeTemplate`, etc. I can really only modify the internals of `SomeTemplate`.

**NOTE:** I'm using Xalan 2.7.1 with [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/). So those tricks are available

Any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::record)" />
```

or even, generically,

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])" />
```

Of course this approach will not work if you process a list of nodes that is not uniform, i.e.:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="here/foo|/somewhere/else/bar" />
```

Position information is lost in such a case, *unless* you store it in a variable and pass that to the called template:

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
<xsl:for-each select="$record">
  <xsl:call-template name="SomeTemplate">
    <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but obviously that would mean some code rewriting, which I realize you want to avoid.

---

Final hint: `position()` does *not* tell you the position of the node within its parent. It tells you the position of the current node *relative to the list of nodes you are processing right now*.

If you only process (i.e. "apply templates to" or "loop over") nodes within one parent, this happens to be the same thing. If you don't, it's not.

Final hint #2: This

```
<xsl:for-each select="/path/to/record">
  <xsl:variable name="record" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$record">
    <xsl:call-template name="SomeTemplate"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

is is equivalent to this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/path/to/record">
  <xsl:call-template name="SomeTemplate"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but the latter works *without* destroying the meaning of `position()`. Calling a template does not change context, so `.` *will* refer to the correct node withing the called template.

Comment: You're the man! I adapted your suggestion to `1 + count(preceding-sibling::*)` and it worked like a charm!

Comment: About your update: In the real-world example, the records are always uniform (though not always called `record`) as they model a table. So there is no union operator of two "incompatible" XPath node-sets. The variable solution wouldn't work because of the complexity of the real-world code

Comment: Thanks for the additional hints about `position()`. Since I'm always looping over uniform elements, in my case, the looping position does coincide with the element index within its parent.

Comment: ;-)... You can stop adding hints now. The example is really simplified to explain the question. The real-world code is much too complex to put in a Stack Overflow question

Comment: @Lukas: Okay, no more hints. ;-) I was more thinking of "the next guy who sees this question", though.